# SP 2016 - MySiteMicroBlog not Upgrading

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, feature-upgrade

I have upgraded my SP 2013 Farm to SP 2016. In reviewing the Health Analyzer Issues I discovered the issue “Databases require upgrade or not supported”. Looking at the “Manage Databases Upgrade Status” interface I discovered that three databases had this issue.

Following the guidance provided in this article - [Database is up to date, but some sites are not completely upgraded](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/05/database-is-up-to-date-but-some-sites-are-not-completely-upgraded.html), I ran some PowerShell commands to complete the upgrades of these sites.

By analyzing the error logs from the upgrade I have derived the following key messages:

- Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'MySiteMicroBlog'
- Feature upgrade action
  'CustomUpgradeAction.MakeMicrofeedListVisible' threw an exception
  upgrading Feature 'MySiteMicroBlog'
- Feature upgrade action
  'CustomUpgradeAction.MakeMicrofeedListVisible' threw an exception
  upgrading Feature 'MySiteMicroBlog'

Breaking this down more I see that the essential error is the feature upgrade for feature MySiteMicroBlog is incomplete.  This error occurs in three web sites, and those three web sites are in three separate Content Databases.

Unfortunately so far I have not found what causes this error or how to fix it.  If anyone else has any advice or can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The feature “MySiteMicroBlog” is about MySite.

To troubleshoot the issue, you could consider deleting the MySite of the users.

And then run SharePoint 2016 products configuration wizard.

Then in SharePoint 2016, you could re-create the MySite of the users.

Comment: I have the same problem and in my case this did not work. I deleted the MySite, when I wanted to create a new one I got an error that the `MySiteMicroBlog` is not installed.